# Command to delete multiple files

Tags: linux, bash, rm

I'm a new student in programming and I'm stuck on a question, which is:

Enter a command to delete all files that have filename starting with logtest, except logtest itself (delete all files starting with 'logtest' followed by one or more characters.)

`rm -r -- !(logtest.*)` didn't work.

Comment: Hint: `?` matches any one character. `*` matches 0 or more. What happens when you combine the two?

Comment: @Shawn: shouldn't you mention `+`, which stands for one or more? Like this, the file `logtest` itself won't be deleted.

Comment: @Dominique No? + isn't a wildcard character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach was not totally wrong. Since you're dealing with a list coming to `STDIN` and `rm` expects parameters, you need to use `xargs`.

Another thing is that you have to escape a dot when you grep for a filename. Your Command should look sth. like this.:

```
ls | grep -v 'logtest\.' | grep 'logtest' | xargs rm
```

Note that you do a doubled grep. The first one to exclude your `logtest.*` itself and the second to include your remaining files with `logtest`.

Comment: Won’t this fail, perhaps quite catastrophically, if there are files with whitespace in their name?

Answer (score 3):

> enter a command to delete all files that have filenames starting with logtest, except logtest itself (delete all files starting with 'logtest' followed by one or more characters.)

```sh
rm logtest?*
```

`?` matches a single character. `*` matches 0 or more. Combine them to match 1 or more characters.

Or if you mean **all** such files, not just ones in a particular directory...

```sh
find / -name "logtest?*" -exec rm \{\} +
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
for file in *; do
    # Ensure that the file is a file and not a directory.
    [ -f "$file" ] && {
        if printf "%s" "$file" | grep "^logtest." > /dev/null; then
            rm -f "$file"
        fi
    }
done
```

This doesn't parse the output of ls, ensures that the file is actually a file and works with spaces aswell (names like "logtest ").

'^' means to match the start of the string so that stuff like "test_logtest" won't be matched, and the '.' at the end ensures that there are characters after the match. `> /dev/null` stands for redirecting the output of the grep command to /dev/null (All content sent there is discarded), which basically hides the grep matches from showing up in the output.